# Magento 2: Create product list grid using ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, product-grid

I want to create product grid with some changes in columns in my custom module. For that I have created custom module.

In layout file I set

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <uiComponent name="product_listing"/>
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product" name="products_list"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

created product_listing.xml in ui_component

and added code of `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml`

But when i visit my url only loading is showing. No error in log and console.

Can any one please tell me why its not working. Also tell me any other way to implement it if any.